# foreach( ... ) key on only - is array_keys(...) the most efficient?

Tags: php, arrays

if I have some code like:

```
foreach(array_keys($array) as $key) 
{
  // work with the array
}
```

I have 2 questions

1. Is array_keys( ... ) called for every single iteration of foreach( ... )? Is it efficient?
2. If I was to compare speed and memory, is the code above faster/more efficient than
   foreach($array as $key => $data )
   {
   // use $key only
   }

Comment: No, array_keys() is only called once, and then foreach iterates over the return values from that single call, but that return is using PHP memory temporarily until the loop terminates: speedwise it's certainly faster, but don't use it with large arrays if you're really tight on memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.)** If `array_keys($array)` would be evaluated in every iteration, then i don't think, the position where you were last time could be remembered, since `array_keys()` would return a fresh array with keys every time, plus it would be really bad in terms of performance, so no. This goes for all expressions which evaluates as some form of iterable, and goes in the first part of a `foreach`.

**2.)** If you iterate on the whole array, then here is what happens:

**a)** `array_keys()` first extracts all the keys from your array, which kind of a mix of a `List` and a `Hashmap` (if you are familiar with java or some strongly typed oo language), and it might be really fast or really slow depending on the implementation of the arrays internal structure and the `array_keys` method. Then if you iterate on the array, you need to do a lookup in every iteration, like `$value = $array[$currentlyIteratedKey];` which also needs some time, especially with string keys.

**b)** The `foreach` loop is a language construct (probably better optimized), and there is no additional lookup, you get the key and the value in every iteration, so i think it would be faster.

Hope it helps, correct me if I'm wrong!

Answer (score -1):

1 - faster when use all array
2 - faster when need to "find" some key and break

Comment: Are you certain about this? Do you have any resources (such as the corresponding source code) to prove it? How do you know this?

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand, "faster when use all array", what do you mean?  
Any reason that makes you say it is faster?

Comment: It's easy I just test it.